# Compare data from two spreadsheets and copy info from one to another based on matches

Tags: vba, excel

Using Excel VBA, I need to look at a column C in one workbook "A" and compare the data with column "B" in workbook "B". If a match is found copy the data from cells "G:I" workbook "B" in the same row the match was made and paste the data into cells "M:O" workbook "A" in the same row the match was made.

Here is the macro Ive come up with, and it finds the match but won't copy over values. Using watches I confirmed the Match.

Thanks for your help!

```
Sub update()

    Dim filename As String
    Dim filedate As String
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim folderyear As String
    Dim i As Double
    Dim j As Double
    Dim LastRow As Range
    Dim TargetLastRow

    filedate = Format(Now, "mm.dd.yyyy")
    folderyear = Format(Now, "yyyy")
    filepath = "Path"
    filename = filedate & " " & "Draft.xlsx"
    Set wbkOpen = Workbooks.Open(filepath & filename, False, True)
    wbkOpen.Worksheets("infosheet").Columns("M:O").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    For i = 1 To wbkOpen.Worksheets("infosheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For j = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If wbkOpen.Worksheets("infosheet").Range("C" & i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j) Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & j & ":I" & j) = wbkOpen.Worksheets("infosheet").Range("M" & i & ":O" & i)
            End If

        Next j
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: how'd you have data filled up?

Comment: @user3598756 sorry, that result was outdated. I have since updated my result.

Comment: Figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it Out! needed to add .Value to the IF statements.

```
Sub update()

Dim filename As String
Dim filedate As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim folderyear As String
Dim i As Double
Dim j As Double
Dim LastRow As Range
Dim TargetLastRow

filedate = Format(Now, "mm.dd.yyyy")
folderyear = Format(Now, "yyyy")
filepath = "Path"
filename = filedate & " " & "Draft.xlsx"
Set wbkOpen = Workbooks.Open(filepath & filename, False, True)
wbkOpen.Worksheets("infosheet").Columns("M:O").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

For i = 1 To wbkOpen.Worksheets("infosheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If wbkOpen.Worksheets("infosheet").Range("C" & i).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j).Value Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & j & ":I" & j).Value = wbkOpen.Worksheets("infosheet").Range("M" & i & ":O" & i).Value
        End If

    Next j
Next i
```

End Sub